# Can we apply the following derivatives to $f(y_1)$ depending on Leibniz Rule?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Can we apply the following derivatives to $f(y_1)$ as below depending on Leibniz  Rule? 
$$f(y)= \lim_{u\to \infty}{\frac{g(y)-\int_{1}^{u}{\frac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^{1+y}}dx}}{h(y)-\int_{1}^{u}{\frac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^{2-y}}dx}}}$$

Now let us supose that the limit results of  $f(y_1)$ will look as $0/0$. Thus by this advantage, can we apply L'Hopital rule to the right side with respect to the parameter $u$?

$$f(y_1)= \lim_{u\to \infty}{\frac{{\frac {d} {du}}(g(y_1)-\int_{1}^{u}{\frac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^{1+y_1}}dx)}}{{\frac {d} {du}}(h(y_1)-\int_{1}^{u}{\frac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^{2-y_1}}dx)}}}$$

$$f(y_1)= \lim_{u\to \infty}{\frac{{\frac{u-\lfloor u \rfloor}{u^{1+y_1}}}}{{\frac{u-\lfloor u \rfloor}{u^{2-y_1}}}}}$$

$$ f(y_1)=\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{u^{2-y_1}}{u^{1+y_1}}$$

Is my way correct ?

Comment: The question keeps changing and I cannot continue to update my answer. Please ask another question instead of changing it

Comment: @Federico , Sorry, but this last shape, if I can take your comment, I will be glad.

Answer (score 0):

> **Old version.** Your first formula doesn't make much sense: the expression
>   $$
> \lim_{u\to\infty} \int_1^u g(x)\,dx
> $$
>   is a constant, usually denoted as $\int_1^\infty g(x)\,dx$, not a function of $u$; therefore in this case its derivative would be $0$.

If instead you mean
$$
f(u) = \int_1^u g(x)\,dx,
$$
then the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) tells you that
$$
f'(u) = g(u)
$$
for all $u$ at which $g$ is continuous; in your case $u\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Z$.

At $u\in\mathbb Z$, your function $f$ admits left and right derivatives equal to the left and right limits $\lim_{s\to u^\pm}g(s)$.

Comment: Oh, *that* Leibniz rule! I thought you were referring to the [other one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule).

Comment: I added some details. You just need the FToC in this case, no need for differentiation under integral sign